# Why have the home releases of the recent Star Wars films been in March?

Tags: production, star-wars, marketing

I've noticed that with *Star Wars* (at least the recent ones) the films get released in cinemas in December and then home release comes out March.

I get they target December for the cinema release because of the Christmas holiday period but is there a reason why the home release seems to fall in March? I don't recall any sort of holiday season for March.

Comment: Maybe because of Ester? ;-)

Comment: @AJ but that'll be April wouldn't it?

Comment: Actually in two cases with the Saga films in the recent trilogy, both with Abrams, they were pushed back. Episode IX for instance, was originally scheduled for May 2019, but Abrams has pushed IX back to December 2019 as well. I know this doesn't answer the "3 Month" release date idea, but just some trivia..

Comment: @Memor-X Easter is usually in April but can be as early as 22nd March (in the western Churches).

Comment: Also the december release of movies has to do with the fact that during summer the majority of new movies come out, reducing the income that comes from people that will not watch SW when something new is available.

Answer (score 9):

***It's not exclusive*** to the Star Wars franchise but as a whole, the DVD/Blu-ray releases has been shortened to release nearly 3-4 months after the movies hit the theatres. Based on the [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/nelsongranados/2015/04/08/changes-to-hollywood-release-windows-are-coming-fast-and-furious/#65871cc86dc7) article:

> It took more than 10 years for the DVD release window to shrink by half to where it is now, yet it only took 3 years for the digital download window to shrink by almost two thirds (see graph).

[image: Forbes graph]

Thus in the current scenario, the optimal dvd release date is 3-4 months with the digital release occuring early on in the 3rd month. Thus based on that Assumption, considering *The Last Jedi* released at **December 15** and the DVD release is scheduled at [**March 27**](https://www.dvdsreleasedates.com/movies/6097/Star-Wars-Episode-VIII-The-Last-Jedi-2017.html), the 3-4 months gap fits...